# MongoDB: Waiting for available socket hanging

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets

So I am using Mongoose's findOneAndUpdate to update a key value in a document.  I am needing to increment that number by one. If it's not in there it should create a new document. It's in a post route in Node.

I have information going to the post route on a button click.  My app requires users to click a button multiple times in succession and i'm getting a `Waiting for available sockets...` at the bottom of my browser and everything hangs.

I am just doing this on my localhost.  At the end of the request once everything "unhangs" I get the following error in my console:
`POST http://localhost:3000/api/songsqueued net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

This is the post route i'm working with:

```
router.post('/api/songsqueued', function(req, res){
    Song.findOneAndUpdate({songId: req.body.songId}, { $inc:{queueTimes: 1} },
        function(err, song){
        if (err) {
            return console.log("Error: " + err)
        }
        if(song){
            song.queueTimes += 1;

            song.save(function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("updated fam")
                }
            });
        } else {

            var song = new Song();

            song.artistName = req.body.artistName;
            song.titleName = req.body.titleName;
            song.songId = req.body.songId;
            song.songImg = req.body.songImg;


            song.save(function(err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error: " + err)
              } else {
                console.log("created fam")
              }
            })

            console.log(song);
            return res.json({message: "SongCreated"}) 
        }

    })
})
```

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Comment: Can you show us the query and where you set the response?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have edited it to show the POST route I made

Comment: You only set the response on creation of a new song; if there is an error or update to a song you don't send the response -- this is what is causing it to hang

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yep that did it! Thank you...did you want to post the solution so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node server needs to send a response to the client in order for the response to complete. If you don't send a response, the connection will timeout and you get the socket hangup. Make sure that you send a response for each condition:

```
if (err) {
  return res.status(500).end("some error message");
}
else if (song) {
  return res.status(200).end("updated");
}
else {
  return res.status(201).end("created");
}
```